# Detect diff between puppet config and actual

Tags: puppet

Is there a puppet command/hack to detect what resources don't match the puppet configuration. After the original setup there have been manual config changes but I don't know which. I am hoping that if puppet can detect config changes to apply updates in puppet files it can also do the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puppet agent -t --noop
```

`-t` is `--test`, so it runs in a verbose mode in the foreground, but with `--noop` there will be no changes. Puppet will log modifications it *would* make.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to know that was possible which you confirmed. Will use it once I fix Error: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are doing it from files:-

```
sudo puppet apply --noop  --modulepath=modules/ manifests/<name>.pp
```